# scrapy pipeline returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, scrapy

In my spider i have two pipelines, One for images one for files,

in the spider i check for a result of images like so

```
if len(self.img_) >= 0:
    item['image_urls'] = self.img_
```

and also do the same for files.

```
if len(self.result) >= 0:
    item['file_urls'] = self.result
```

my settings are like so for the Pipelines

```
'ScrawlerScraper.images.ImgPipeline': 1,
'ScrawlerScraper.fld_pipeline.FilesPipeline': 2
```

My process item in the image pipeline that comes first is like so

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            request = [x for x in item['image_urls']]
            for x in request:
                dfd = spider.crawler.engine.download(x, spider)
                dfd.addBoth(self.return_item, item)
                return dfd
        except logging.info('No images'): 
            return item
```

This is the same for the files pipeline

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            request = [x for x in item['file_urls']]
            for x in request:
                dfd = spider.crawler.engine.download(x, spider)
                dfd.addBoth(self.return_item, item)
                return dfd
        except logging.error('No Files Problem'):
            return item
```

I do this because i am getting multiple images and can only yield the item once in the spider.

What i dont understand is why i am getting an error in the second pipeline

```
fld_pipeline.py", line 23, in process_item
request = [x for x in item['file_urls']]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

if there is no `item['file_urls']` the pipeline should not even execute.

Im totaly lost as to what is happening.

Thanks for any help and i hope my question is not to badly formated..

This is where i check for a file that exits and return item if not. maybe i have it wrong where i am in a loop and trying to return the item.
but it comes back to the next pipeline as none

```
 for x in item['image_urls']:
        try:
            a = urlparse.urlparse(x)
        except TypeError:
            logging.info('No images')
            return item
        file_name = os.path.basename(a.path)
        try:
            u = sock.Worker().get_url(x)
        except TypeError:
            logging.info('No images')
            return item
        if u:
            try:
                os.path.exists(settings.get('IMAGES_STORE') + file_name)
                logging.info("Image Already Downloaded: %s " % a.path)
                item['image_urls'].append(settings.get('IMAGES_STORE') + file_name)
                return item
            except TypeError:
                data = u.read()
                with open(settings.get('IMAGES_STORE') + file_name, 'wb') as code:
                    code.write(data)
                    logging.info("Downloading (%s)" % a.path,)
                item['image_urls'].append(settings.get('IMAGES_STORE') + file_name)
                return item
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you are trying to index an object (as in `object[key]`), but this does not work if the object is `None`. So it seems that someone or something is calling the function `process_item` with an argument `item` equal to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Your try/except clause isn't right. You must list error types after except instead of saying it what to log. Try this:

```
    try:
        request = [x for x in item['image_urls']]
        for x in request:
            dfd = spider.crawler.engine.download(x, spider)
            dfd.addBoth(self.return_item, item)
            return dfd
    except TypeError:
        logging.info('No images') 
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex K
that was a problem

Comment: I still have the issue with image pipelines returning items as none to the files pipelines.
I think i have got it wrong where i am checking if a files exists within a for loop.

Comment: I have updated the code to show return item in the first pipleline